# $_SESSION var no passed

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have php page which contains two javascript functions like this:

```
function PregledDokumenta(id)
{
    var info = id.split('-');
    var vrdok = info[0];
    var brdok = info[1];

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Php/Dokument/Pregled.php",
        data: { vrDok: vrdok, brDok: brdok },
        success: function(returnedData)
        {
            document.getElementById('Content').innerHTML = returnedData;
            <?php 
                $_SESSION['vrDok'] = vrdok;
                $_SESSION['brDok'] = brdok;
            ?>

    <?php
        $a = $_SESSION['vrDok'];
        echo("alert($a);");
        ?>
        }
    });
}

function UnosNoveStavke()
{
    var vrdok = <?php echo($_SESSION['vrDok']);?>;
    var brdok = <?php echo($_SESSION['brDok']);?>;

    <?php
        $a = $_SESSION['vrDok'];
        echo("alert($a);");
        ?>
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Php/Dokument/IzborRobe.php",
        data: {vrDok: vrdok, brDok: brdok},
        success: function(returnedData)
        {
            document.getElementById('Content').innerHTML = returnedData;
        }
    })
}
```

So when i load page and press button i run `PregledDokumenta(id)` function. In there i pass some values from `id` of element and then i echo back some other text and buttons as you can see i alert `$_SESSION['vrDok']` to see if it is assigned and it returns value. Then when i click button (about 10 sec after running first function) that i echoed back from first function i run second `UnosNoveStavke` function. There you can see I again alert to see if `$_SESSION` return value but it return `undefined`. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very confused regarding how `JavaScript` and `PHP` communicate with each other!

For example, with the following code, you are effectively trying to assign `JavaScript` variables, which you get from an AJAX request, into `PHP` sections:

```
<?php 
    $_SESSION['vrDok'] = vrdok;
    $_SESSION['brDok'] = brdok;
?>
```

This can't work, because all `PHP` expressions are evaluated before the page even loads.

If you need to save these values in `PHP` sessions, you have to do it either in the file the AJAX request is sent, in your case `Pregled.php`, or a `PHP` file that you include in it.